# How to stop multiple subplots overlapping in mathplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I want to display two pie-charts, well donut charts, side by side. But using the code below all I'm getting is overlapping graphs. I've tried using various values for subplot adjust but the legends always end up overlapping. Chopped out all the non relevant code in the function

[image]

```
#Function to draw graphs for sports data
        
    #Create figure with two subplots
    fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,2,subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))
    j=0
    
    #Loop through all columns we want to graph
    for type in types:
                  
        #Create a pie chart
        wedges, texts, autotexts = ax[j].pie(to_plot,         
                explode=explode,  
                labels=labels,     
                colors=colors,      
                autopct=lambda pct: func(pct, data), 
                pctdistance=0.8,    
                counterclock=False, 
                startangle=90,      
                wedgeprops={'width': 0.75}, 
                radius=1.75       
                )

        #Set label colors
        for text in texts:
            text.set_color('grey')

        #Create legend
        ax[j].legend(wedges, leg_labels,
            title=title,
            title_fontsize="x-large",
            loc="center left",
            bbox_to_anchor=(1.5, 0, 0.5, 1),
            prop={'size': 12})

        j += 1
    
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=0.5, hspace=None)
    plt.show()
    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bbox setting that determines the position of the legend is set to the right of each pie chart, so they overlap. Therefore, we can avoid overlapping the legends by setting the respective positions for the graphs.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Some data
labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
fracs = [15, 30, 45, 10]
titles = ['20 members\nfollow Basketball','23 members\nfollow Basketball']
legend_pos = ['center left','center right']
bboxes = [(-1.0, 0, 0.5, 1),(1.5, 0, 0.5, 1)]
# Make figure and axes
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))

for i in range(2):
    wedges, texts,_ = axs[i].pie(fracs,
                                 labels=labels,
                                 autopct='%.0f%%',
                                 shadow=True,
                                 explode=(0, 0.1, 0, 0),
                                 wedgeprops=dict(width=0.6))
    
    axs[i].legend(wedges,
                 labels,
                 title=titles[i],
                 title_fontsize="x-large",
                 loc=legend_pos[i],
                 bbox_to_anchor=bboxes[i],
                 prop={'size': 12})
    
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This example is a customized response to an example from an official reference. If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer